# Can the java utc time fit inside a double?

Tags: java, utc

I have a method that expects a double, and I want to store the UTC time and my variable that I am passing to this method is a long.

I am using:

```
Date now = new Date();
now.getTime()
```

to get the UTC time.

Can this value not fit into a double?

Comment: I suggest you read up on Java's primitive datatypes (well, datatypes in general). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It will "fit", in the sense that `double` can represent any `long` value, but there would be a loss of precision for dates far in the distant future (100,000's of years from now).

The [IEEE 754](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#section_1) spec, which double uses, uses up to only 53 bits for the non-exponent part of the number. Since long is 64 bits, roughly speaking you'll potentially lose precision if the `long` value exceeds 53 bits.

However, 53 bits can accurately represent the current [epoch millisecond time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) `long` value, which requires only 41 bits.

A loss of precision will not occur until the epoch time exceeds 2<sup>53</sup>, which won't occur until `Oct 12 287396`.

Even at the worst case, 11 bits of "inaccuracy" would still translate to a time value with an accuracy of about ±1 second (`2 ^ 11 = 2048`, which in milliseconds is a range of 2 seconds).

In short, converting an epoch time to `double` is OK.